# GUI Framework JavaFX or Swing

Tags: java

I'm new to java and want to programm a little data manager.
It should hold only a few data to give me a overview.

Now the question is whis framework to use. JavaFX or Swing?
What is the easery one?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318645/javafx-or-swing

Comment: Tell us whether it's for private use or business

Comment: It is a private project only for me

Comment: Then you are totaly free. I prefers JavaFX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like it's a private project. So you should use JavaFX because it's newer and look modern.
And for private use it's no prolem using newes jre which include javaFX runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Since i assume that you want a desktop applicaiton i would start with swing. In my opinion swing should be included in every java - basic knowledge and therefore you should get your head into it. 
Moreover you are able to integrate JavaFx into existing swing - applications.

[Fast Swing Tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFQQFjAE&url=http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-tutorial&ei=zQOCUpTkFYHp4wT_0YC4Bg&usg=AFQjCNFOT7xilj9yoX6iXhw20FN0mtE2gA&sig2=lGe9_p0TL2R2cDQllMsaaw&bvm=bv.56146854,d.bGE)

And if you want to improve your application you can take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what your requirements are. If your users cannot migrate to Java 7, or if cannot impose Java 7 on them, then forget about JavaFX.

I would say Swing is easier because it is a more mature technology. You will find tons of discussions about it and ready-to-use components, free or paid.

I am starting to use JavaFX and for me the main benefit is its support for multimedia, which it seems you do not need. Also, if you start on Swing you can migrate to JavaFX later if you regret your decision.